# How to use Python multiprocessing to prepare images for pygame

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame, python-multiprocessing, pygame-surface

I'm making a slideshow app with that oh-so-naught-ies pan and zoom effect. I'm using pygame.

The main display is therefore realtime 30fps+, and I don't want it stuttering when it has to load a new image - this takes it over 1/30th of a second.

So I wanted to use some parallel process to prepare the images and feed the main process with these objects, which are instances of a class.

I've tried with **threading** and with multiprocess. Threading 'works' but it's still jumpy (I blame [python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/16/python-parallelizing-cpu-bound-tasks-with-multiprocessing/)) - the whole thing slows down when the thread is busy! So the code ran but it didn't meet the goal of allowing a continually smooth display.

But **multiprocess** segfaults `(pygame parachute)` as soon as I call a method on the received prepared image from the main process. I've tried pipe and queue communications - both result in the same problem. The method runs up until it does a call to

```
sized = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, newsize )
```

Then there's the segfault. This class does not have any dependencies from the main process.

Does pygame just not like multiprocessing? Is there another way that is compatible? Is there a way to 'nice' secondary threads that might stop the threading method performing?

Any help greatly appreciated. Happy to post more code, just ask in comments, but didn't want to dump a big listing here unless needed.

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT

This is as short as I could make it. **You need to provide three paths to jpeg files in the constructor at the bottom**.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import pygame
import sys
import time
import re
import os
import pickle
from random import randrange, shuffle
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import Queue


class Img:
    """The image objects I need to pass around"""
    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (640,480))

    def getSurface(self):
        """Get a surface, blit our image onto it in right place."""
        surface = pygame.Surface((640,480))
        # xxx this next command fails
        sized = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (640,480))
        surface.blit(sized, (0,0))
        return surface

class Floaty:
    """demo"""
    def __init__(self, fileList):
        self.fileList = fileList
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

        # open the first image to get it going
        self.img = Img(self.fileList.pop())

        # Set up parallel process for opening images
        self.parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
        self.feeder = Process(target=asyncPrep, args=(child_conn,))
        self.feeder.start()

    def draw(self):
        """draw the image"""
        # collect image ready-prepared by other process
        if self.parent_conn.poll():
            self.img = self.parent_conn.recv()
            print ("received ", self.img)

        # request new image
        self.parent_conn.send(self.fileList.pop())

        self.screen.blit(self.img.getSurface(), (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()

def asyncPrep(conn):
    """load up the files"""

    while True:
        if conn.poll(1):
            filename = conn.recv()
            print ("doing ", filename)
            img = Img(filename)
            conn.send(img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fileList = ['/path/to/a.jpg', 'path/to/b.jpg', 'path/to/c.jpg']
    f = Floaty(fileList)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while 1:
        f.draw()
        clock.tick(4);
```

When I run this (Python 2.7.6) I get:

```
('doing ', '/path/to/a.jpg')
('received ', <__main__.Img instance at 0x7f2dbde2ce60>)
('doing ', '/path/to/b.jpg')
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
zsh: abort (core dumped)
```

Comment: A short compilable example would help (if that's possible). Anyway: How did you send the image, can you serialize it somehow and then send it? It's probably a memory issue (threading is sharing memory, multiprocess is not).

Comment: @isset thanks, pls see edited Q. I also tried pickling the thing but I get a 'Surface cannot be pickled' error.

Comment: Hey, so I came across a pretty similar solution to you, where you load in the image to a string buffer in another process, then send that buffer to your main process where your openGL context resides. I think that's why you were getting a crash before, you were trying to access the openGL context from outside the main process.

You say this solution works for you, but I still get minor stuttering when calling pygame.image.frombuffer() in the main process, as this is a blocking call to copy the buffer to video memory. Curious if you've seen any stuttering, etc? Anything special I'm missing? Thx

Comment: So what I did was to use the parallel process to open the image **and scale it down** to the max size needed by the parent process. This way my buffer is relatively small and fast to load.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using multiprocessing by making the Img class load the image into a string buffer, stored in a property, then adding a `postReceive` method which loads it into a surface stored in the image property.

The `postReceive` method is called by the parent process after receiving the `Img` object from the child.

Therefore the object created by the child is not bound to anything pygame-y.

```
    self.imageBuffer = pygame.image.tostring(
      pygame.transform.scale(image, (640,480)),
      'RGB')
```

Then, the new method in `Img` is simply:

```
def: postReceive(self):
    self.image = pygame.image.frombuffer( self.imagebuffer, 'RGB' )
```

Add a call to this here:

```
    # collect image ready-prepared by other process
    if self.parent_conn.poll():
        self.img = self.parent_conn.recv().postReceive()
        print ("received ", self.img)
```